# Deserializing XML using XStream does not work in OSGi (Java 1.4)

Tags: java, maven, osgi, xstream, java1.4

I created some OSGi-bundles. One of these has a function to export data to xml using XStream. It just works fine. Also importing again when using the Bundle as library and not within an OSGi context, works.

But if I call my import within another bundle I get a "com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException" with the follwing Debugging Information printed out:

```
---- Debugging information ----
message             : Cannot find class ChildDate
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ObjectAccessException
cause-message       : Cannot find class ChildData
class               : ChildData
required-type       : ChildData
path                : /ParentData/ChildData
-------------------------------
message             : Could not call ParentData.readObject()
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : Cannot find class ParentData : Cannot find class ChildData
class               : ParentData
required-type       : ChildData
path                : /ParentData/ChildData
-------------------------------
```

I think it's a similar problem to this: [XStream and OSGi](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@felix.apache.org/msg05229.html) or this: [CannotResolveClassException in OSGi environment](http://old.nabble.com/CannotResolveClassException-in-OSGi-environment-td18847137.html)

So I tried to solve it setting the ClassLoader. But it does not work.

Parts of my ParentData class:

```
public class ParentData implements Serializable {
  // [...]
  private static ClassLoader classLoaderForImport = ParentData.class.getClassLoader();
  // [...]
  public static void setClassLoaderForImport(ClassLoader classLoaderForImport) {
    ParentData.classLoaderForImport = classLoaderForImport;
  }
  // [...]
  public static Lumicon importFromXMLFile(String path) {
    return importFromFile(new DomDriver(), path);
  }
  private static ParentData importFromFile(HierarchicalStreamDriver driver, String path) {
    try {
      XStream xstream = new XStream(driver);
      //set the classloader as the default one won't work in any case
      xstream.setClassLoader(ParentData.classLoaderForImport);
      xstream.alias("ParentData", classLoaderForImport.loadClass(ParentData.class.getName()));//ParentData.class);
      xstream.alias("ChildData", classLoaderForImport.loadClass(ChildData.class.getName()));//ChildData.class);
      Reader reader = new FileReader(path);
      Object object = xstream.fromXML(reader);
      return (ParentData) object;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
      System.out.println("This did not work.");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("File " + path + " not found.");
    }
  }
// [...]
}
```

The function `xstream.fromXML(reader)` does not work, but `classLoaderForImport.loadClass(ChildData.class.getName())` doesn't fail.

This is how I call it from another Bundle:

```
ParentData.setClassLoaderForImport(ParentData.class.getClassLoader());
data = ParentData.importFromXMLFile(path); // this is where the Exception happens
```

I also tried `this.getClass().getClassLoader()` and `ChildData.class.getClassLoader()`

Could it be, that this does not work, because this function is called from a third bundle?

Some more Info:

- Java version: 1.4 (no, I can not upgrade to 1.5 or 1.6)
- Execution environment: J2SE-1.6
- Maven Version: 2.2.1
- Running with Pax Runner (1.5.0) from OPS4J - http://www.ops4j.org
- OSGi: Equinox 3.6.0
- XStream 1.3.1 (com.springsource.com.thoughtworks.xstream)

Any help would be very welcome!

Comment: "Could not call ParentData.readObject()" Does this method exist? If it does, can we see it?

Comment: There's a weird thing in the error message as well, could be a typo, but maybe a clue: "Cannot find class ChildDat**e**" is in the original message (but not the cause-message, strangely).

Comment: @biziclop 1. readObject() does not exist. That was the problem. 2. Yes, that was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your question contains all the relevant code, the problem is given away by the following:

```
Could not call ParentData.readObject()
```

You have declared that your `ParentData implements Serializable`. Although the `Serializable` interface does not include any methods, both Java serialization and XStream expect a `readObject` and a `writeObject`. I'm a little rusty on the exact situations in which these are mandatory, but I would suggest you to remove the `implements Serializable` from the `ParentData` class.

Comment: That was pretty easy, I didn't know this about Serializable. Now I feel dumb :P